# Custom dedicated email server combined with Amazon AWS?

Tags: smtp, amazon-ec2, email-server

We are considering moving our servers to Amazone EC2 cloud. The only thing that stops right now is their problems with ip ranges banned from spam mail lists like SORBS.

We are considering leaving one dedicated server in our current hosting, the one which we use to send mail (and other several features we will move to EC2), in order to be able to send the mails from this smtp server instead from Amazon.

So, the idea is to have our sites hosted in EC2, and when they need to send mail, redirect they to our "local" smtp server.

Do you think it´s viable? Can you think on a better solution?

Thanks in advance, Simon.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly viable - any mail server will allow you to forward all outbound mail to a specific host and this is done regularly for different reasons. Just make sure you lock down that outbound box so it only accepts mail from your servers.

Another possible solution - some of the hosted email hygiene companies (Postini, MessageLabs, etc) support outbound filtering so if you happen to be in the market for hosted antispam/antivirus, you could also route your outbound mail through them instead of your own dedicated box.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP Relay is definitely possible with any Email server. In this case, all emails will go to an external SMTP Server and then onto outside.

If you want to move all your servers and not want to have a local SMTP Server, consider a [SMTP Relay service](http://www.safentrix.com/outbound). They will also additionally do Virus/SPAM scanning for you.